# oneApi 2021.4 xilink: : error : Assertion failed (shared/driver/drvutils.c line 312)

Tags: intel-oneapi

Using newly installed oneAPI 2021.4 + VisualStudio 16.11.3.

Create new project - Console App -

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {std::cout << "Hello World!\n";}
```

After rebuilding I get:

Rebuild started...

> 1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: xilink, Configuration: Debug
> Win32 ------ 1>xilink: : error : Assertion failed
> (shared/driver/drvutils.c, line 312) 1>Done building project
> "xilink.vcxproj" -- FAILED.

Tried on many other projects, x32 and x64, other VS versions - the error is the same.

I have found workaround - I copied file xilink.exe  from older version 2021.2 to 2021.4 folder - and linking start working!

> C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\2021.2.0\windows\bin\intel64\xilink.exe

was copied to

> C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\2021.4.0\windows\bin\intel64\xilink.exe

(and intel64_ia32 was copied too..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue raised by you has been fixed in Intel oneAPI 2022.1 version. Please download and let us know if this resolves your issue.

As a workaround you can copy a file clang.exe (by default it is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\latest\windows\bin) to the folder with xilink (for x64 configuration it is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\latest\windows\bin\intel64).